# REST API using 'slug's instead of '_id's

Tags: node.js, rest, backbone.js, mongoose

I am trying to figure out an elegant way to create an REST API for a site that primarily only deals with `slugs` and not `ids`. This API is to be written in Node.JS/Express/MongoDB/Mongoose with a Backbone Marionette/Backbone-Relational frontend.

I do not need to ever deal with the typical `_id` directly, as I aim for my endpoints to be something like `/api/articles/some-article-title`.

I was originally thinking actually using both `_ids` and `slugs` with something like this, getting it to dynamically return an new `id` field.

```
// Inside my controller

var slugQuery = function(slug){
    var query = {$or: [{slug: slug}]};
    if (slug.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        query.$or.push({_id: slug});
    }
    return query;
}

exports.getProfile = function (req, res) {
    var slug = req.params.slug;

    Profile.findOne( slugQuery(slug), function(err, profile){
        if(err){
            // DB Error
            res.status(400);
            res.end();
        }else if(!profile){
            res.status(404);
            res.end();
        }else{
            res.json( profile.withId() );
        }
    });
};


// Method added to the model

ProfileSchema.methods.withId = function() {
    var json = this.toObject();

    // Use the slug or id
    json.id = json.slug || json._id;

    return json;
};
```

This seems hacky to me, especially as there are quite a few endpoints/models that would need to function like this. It gets even more complex when I'm wanting to do fairly deep document linking utilising Mongooses `populate` functionality.

I know theoretically you 'can' literally do away with the `ObjectID` and store the `slug` directly inside the _id field, but you cannot update the `_id` field once its been inserted, and also you would need to update all related links to the document if it did indeed change.

To me, this seems like quite a common need, an REST compliant endpoint with `slug` based identifiers.

Has anybody had to build something like this before? Any best practices on this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018100/identify-item-by-either-an-id-or-a-slug-in-a-restful-api.  Note that `populate` works off `_id`, though it doesn't need to be an ObjectId, so if you wanted to  utilize it you'd need to replace the `_id` with your slug.  Though `populate` doesn't exactly do anything sophisticated; you could always just load related docs in your own subsequent query.  Personally I'm a fan of the way SO does URLs.  Identified by id, but redirecting to a URL with a human readable suffix (title, username, etc)

Comment: I have the same requirement and decided to just use `slug` in my front-end and let `_id` be. I use `_id` internally (to populate) and don't even expose it publicly. Or does your front-end already exist and uses `_id`?